# ngircd refuses connection over ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

This might be just a misunderstanding of how ssh tunneling works, but here goes:

In my `ngirgd.conf` file I have the following:

```
Ports = 6669
Listen = 127.0.0.1
```

This ngircd server is running on **HostA**. I've tunneled into it using the following:

> wayne@**HostB** % ssh -N wayne@**HostA** -L 6669:**HostA**:6669

I enter my password. Then inside irssi on **HostB**, I do:

```
/connect localhost 6669
```

And I get

```
Looking up localhost
Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 6668
Connection to localhost established
Connection lost to localhost
```

Inside the terminal window where I launched the tunnel, I get:

```
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

From what I've understood, the ssh tunnel should be connecting `HostB:6669` to `HostA:6669`, so as far as ngirgd is concerned, the connection came from localhost/127.0.0.1. But it appears this is not the case - when I forwarded to port 80 it connected to my server just fine.

Am I misunderstanding something, or is something wrong? And how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ssh` manpage mentions your use-case in section "TCP FORWARDING"](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh&sektion=1#TCP+FORWARDING).

Spot the difference? Try this:

```
ssh -L 6669:127.0.0.1:6669 hostB
```

Your IRC daemon listens to `127.0.0.1:6669` *on `hostb`* and the `host:hostport` part of `-L port:host:hostpart` is *relative to the server you connect to*.  So I guess `hostb` doesn't resolve to `127.0.0.1` (from `hostb`), does it?  (Thus your command tries to connect to `hostb:6669` where *no daemon listens*.)

Comment: It appears that the guide I was looking at was full of crap (or, misinformation). I just found the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5823988/344286), too.